# How to parse EE tag in Forums template?

Tags: templates, parsing, codeigniter, forum, themes

**EE tag in Forum template**

What I need is to use my custom EE plugin in to Forum header template:
themes/forum_themes/default/forum_global/html_header.html

I see that Forum template are processed by CI parser (is right?).

A workaround is include in html_header.html a processed EE template,
or call EE Template Class to process EE template.

What dou you think?

Comment: Please expand your question to help us understand what you are trying to do so we can help you do it.

Let us know: what you want to do, what you've tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use regular EE tags in forum templates unless you [run the forums through regular templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/forum/other_features.html#running-the-forums-through-regular-templates).

> The down side of this approach is that it adds more processing
>   overhead, so it’s not recommended unless users really need this
>   capability. Since the forum can’t be cached, on very busy sites this
>   can create some unwanted server load.

Comment: No, I'm not talkin about regular templates. Thanks